# rearrange array data according to value and update key name

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

here is one array:

```
$return = Array (
    [9:00] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [iScheduleID] => 13                    
            [iAdminID] => 4
            [vStaff] => Ms. Lily
            [vStudent] => Taylor Osborn
            [iPositionID] => 0
        ),
        [1] => Array (
            [iScheduleID] => 14
            [iAdminID] => 4
            [vStaff] => Ms. Lily
            [vStudent] => Smaran Meesala
            [iPositionID] => 0
        ),
        [2] => Array (
            [iScheduleID] => 1
            [iAdminID] => 3
            [vStaff] => Ms. Sanchita
            [vStudent] => Darian Newell
            [iPositionID] => 2
        ),     
        [4] => Array (
            [iScheduleID] => 26
            [iAdminID] => 5
            [vStaff] => Ms. Timberly
            [vStudent] => Layla Shunnarah
            [iPositionID] => 4
        ),
        [5] => Array (
            [iScheduleID] => 27
            [iAdminID] => 5
            [vStaff] => Ms. Timberly
            [vStudent] => Haidi Sanchez
            [iPositionID] => 4
        )
    )
)
```

You can see that:

**CASE 1:**
there are 2 times iPositionID = 0 because they have both iAdminID are same, so one iPositionID should be as 0 and another one should as 1. this is the same for iAdminID 5.

**CASE 2:**
now, you can see that iAdminID 3 is only once so it has iPositionID is 2 and iPositionID 3 has been skipped.

Expected result:

```
$return = Array (
    [9:00] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [iScheduleID] => 13                    
            [iAdminID] => 4
            [vStaff] => Ms. Lily
            [vStudent] => Taylor Osborn
            [iPositionID] => 0
        ),
        [1] => Array (
            [iScheduleID] => 14
            [iAdminID] => 4
            [vStaff] => Ms. Lily
            [vStudent] => Smaran Meesala
            [iPositionID] => 1
        ),
        [2] => Array (
            [iScheduleID] => 1
            [iAdminID] => 3
            [vStaff] => Ms. Sanchita
            [vStudent] => Darian Newell
            [iPositionID] => 2
        ),     
        [4] => Array (
            [iScheduleID] => 26
            [iAdminID] => 5
            [vStaff] => Ms. Timberly
            [vStudent] => Layla Shunnarah
            [iPositionID] => 4
        ),
        [5] => Array (
            [iScheduleID] => 27
            [iAdminID] => 5
            [vStaff] => Ms. Timberly
            [vStudent] => Haidi Sanchez
            [iPositionID] => 5
        )
    )
)
```

this is what i tried:

```
<?php    
$nine = $return['9:00'];
$total_nine = count($nine);
$t1['nine'] = $nine;

for ($i=0; $i < $total_nine; $i++) {
    $t = $t1['nine'][$i]['iAdminID'];

    if($t == 4) {
        $t1['nine'][$i]['iPositionID'] = 0;
    } else if($t == 3) {
        $t1['nine'][$i]['iPositionID'] = 2;
    } else if($t == 5) {
        $t1['nine'][$i]['iPositionID'] = 4;
    }
}    
?>
```

Comment: Same `iAdminID` only happens twice?

Comment: @Emerald yes.. for now it will happens twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your solution

**Input**

```
$return = array(
    '9:00' => array(
        array(
            'iScheduleID' => 13,
            'iAdminID' => 4,
            'vStaff' => 'Ms. Lily',
            'vStudent' => 'Taylor Osborn',
            'iPositionID' => 0
        ),
        array(
            'iScheduleID' => 14,
            'iAdminID' => 4,
            'vStaff' => 'Ms. Lily',
            'vStudent' => 'Smaran Meesala',
            'iPositionID' => 0
        ),
        array(
            'iScheduleID' => 1,
            'iAdminID' => 3,
            'vStaff' => 'Ms. Sanchita',
            'vStudent' => 'Darian Newell',
            'iPositionID' => 2
        ),
        array(
            'iScheduleID' => 26,
            'iAdminID' => 5,
            'vStaff' => 'Ms. Timberly',
            'vStudent' => 'Layla Shunnarah',
            'iPositionID' => 4
        ),
        array(
            'iScheduleID' => 27,
            'iAdminID' => 5,
            'vStaff' => 'Ms. Timberly',
            'vStudent' => 'Haidi Sanchez',
            'iPositionID' => 4
        )
    )
);
```

**Solution**

```
$position = array();//for add iPositionID
$new = array();
foreach($return['9:00'] as $row){

    if(in_array($row['iPositionID'],$position)) $row['iPositionID'] = ($row['iPositionID']+1);//Check current iPositionID is in $position array. If = Yes then +1 in current row['iPositionID']

    $position[] = $row['iPositionID']; //add $row['iPositionID'] value in $position array

    $new['9:00'][$row['iPositionID']] = $row; //new values in $new array
}
echo "<pre>";print_r($new);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [9:00] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [iScheduleID] => 13
                    [iAdminID] => 4
                    [vStaff] => Ms. Lily
                    [vStudent] => Taylor Osborn
                    [iPositionID] => 0
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [iScheduleID] => 14
                    [iAdminID] => 4
                    [vStaff] => Ms. Lily
                    [vStudent] => Smaran Meesala
                    [iPositionID] => 1
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [iScheduleID] => 1
                    [iAdminID] => 3
                    [vStaff] => Ms. Sanchita
                    [vStudent] => Darian Newell
                    [iPositionID] => 2
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [iScheduleID] => 26
                    [iAdminID] => 5
                    [vStaff] => Ms. Timberly
                    [vStudent] => Layla Shunnarah
                    [iPositionID] => 4
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [iScheduleID] => 27
                    [iAdminID] => 5
                    [vStaff] => Ms. Timberly
                    [vStudent] => Haidi Sanchez
                    [iPositionID] => 5
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: key must be same as iPositionID. in ur output see the key of iPositionid 4. it must be 4 not 3..

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `iAdminID` is always with value of `4, 3 or 5`. You can set position array first with corresponding starting value then increment every each loop iteration

```
$nine = $return['9:00'];
$total_nine = count($nine);
$t1['nine'] = $nine;
$position = array(4 => 0, 3 => 2, 5 => 4); // set position array
for ($i=0; $i < $total_nine; $i++) {
    $t = $t1['nine'][$i]['iAdminID'];
    if($t == 4) {
        $t1['nine'][$i]['iPositionID'] = $position[$t];
    } else if($t == 3) {
        $t1['nine'][$i]['iPositionID'] = $position[$t];
    } else if($t == 5) {
        $t1['nine'][$i]['iPositionID'] = $position[$t];
    }
    $position[$t]++;
}

print_r($t1);
```